# Acumatica Web Services - Get data from Generic Enquiry

Tags: rest, web-services, acumatica

We are following the below Blog link. However the Results does not populate. In addition, adding fields to the current Results screen does not pull through onto the Service Body.

https://www.acumatica.com/blog/contract-based-apis-in-generic-inquiries/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59zbU.png)

```
{
    "id": "30225908-c2b0-4013-9500-93606424f85a",
    "rowNumber": 1,
    "note": null,
    "ResultFilter": [
        {
            "id": "c4bfa8f3-ad41-ea11-a821-000d3a4721ed",
            "rowNumber": 1,
            "note": null,
            "CurrentPrice": {
                "value": 0.000000
            },
            "InventoryID": {
                "value": "420000013000"
            },
            "LastCost": {
                "value": 0.0
            },
            "PurchaseUnit": {
                "value": "METRE"
            },
            "QtyDisbursed": {},
            "QtyOnHand": {
                "value": "0.000000"
            },
            "WarehouseID": {
                "value": "PRD-FINN"
            },
            "custom": {},
            "files": []
        }}
```

Comment: Please double check that you have $expand=Result in the query

Comment: Hi Dmitrii, yes that is the first thing we did, but its not listing the newly added fields

Comment: Have you mapped new fields in both GI and Endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GI Enquiry Access, to retrieve and modify the service point that pulls from the GI, the user's role needs to have screen EDIT access. the 'Not Set' will be seen as revoked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXyp4.png)

Answer (score 0):

looking at your mapping of the fields, you are missing the Mapped object column.

Please add the field using the populate button. that way the field will get mapped properly.

Comment: Hi Samol, the populate button yields no results on the screen, Acumatica Dev support has asked us to restart the application as we also believe the issue lies with the population